# How do I accept numbers that are only multiples of 5 in TypeScript?

Tags: typescript

Not sure if this is possible, but was curious, hence the question. I was building a component that houses an square image which takes in a `size` prop. I would like to enforce that the `size` value is always a multiple of `5` so the image remains crisp.

My meager knowledge on the topic led me to this, but doesn't really work the way I expected it to.

```js
type Props = {
  size: (x) => (x % 5 === 0)
};
```

At the end of the day, I just want to be able to type check my props as I'm using them. For example:

```js
// TS should throw an error
<Logo size={32} />

// TS should allow it
<Logo size={40} />
```

Is something like this possible with TypeScript?

Comment: What *precisely* do you mean by "doesn't really work the way I expected it to"?

Comment: @kaya3 types/interfaces do not accept function definitions, so can't add logic there.

Comment: But what is the way you expected this to work?

Comment: I wouldn't use the type system to enforce this. I think I would just round the number to the nearest multiple of 5 within the component itself. You could make this behavior explicit by adding a property `roundSize` which must be set to true, together with some JSDoc explaining why this size rounding is beneficial.

Comment: @kaya3 Ah, got it. I've updated the question to explain the desired outcome.

Comment: @Luc Right now, that's how I'm holding down the fort (I throw an error instead of rounding up, so that's a nice touch), but I asked the question to see if there was a smarter "more TypeScript" way to do this. But a valid answer for those looking for a quick solution, thank you :)

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Very very interesting question and TS shines here :))
Starting from 4.1 you can have this example.

Since all multipliers of 5 end with either zero or five you can
solve it like this

```
type EndsWithZeroOrFive = '0' | '5'
type OtherDigits = `${number}` | ''
type MultiplierOfFive = `${OtherDigits}${EndsWithZeroOrFive}`

const n1 : MultiplierOfFive = '10' 
const n2 : MultiplierOfFive = '25' 
// no issue

const n3 : MultiplierOfFive = '12' 
// Type '"12"' is not assignable to type 'EndsWithZeroOrFive | `${number}0` | `${number}5`'.
```

Comment: That's only accepted from string not number.

Comment: Very smart idea, using [template literal types](https://www.typescriptlang.org/docs/handbook/2/template-literal-types.html) to stitch up an entirely new type. The idea was that the component should accept numbers, but strings could work too. I'll keep the question open for any other potential solutions since it's still quite early, but I like the way you think :)

Comment: I've added an edit that, when accepted, will show how to use numbers.

Answer (score 1):

It is possible to validate a number:

```js
type ZeroOrFive = '0' | '5'

type IsValid<N extends number> = `${N}` extends '5' | `${number}${ZeroOrFive}` ? N : never

type Result = IsValid<5> // 5

const fn = <Num extends number>(num: IsValid<Num>) => num

fn(10) // ok
fn(5) // ok
fn(125) // ok

fn(11) // Error
fn(0) // Error
fn(NaN) // Error
fn(Infinity) // Error
fn(05) // Error
fn('05') // Error


const higherOrder = (num: number) => fn(num); // error with higher order function
```

[Playground](http://tsplay.dev/mx6KZw)

The trick is in using conditional type with generic argument.

If you are interested in a validation of generic arguments, you can check my articles [here](https://catchts.com/type-negation) and [here](https://catchts.com/validators)